# how to read a .csv file as time series using zoo?

Tags: r, file, csv, file-io, zoo

I am trying to read a .csv file into R as time series using zoo package.That's what I've written so far:

```
tbl<-as.xts(read.zoo("~//Documents//thesis research//myseries (version 1)2.csv",sep="/",header=T,format=%m/%d/%Y))
```

I 've got a following error message:

```
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "tbl<-as.xts(read.zoo("~//Documents//thesis research//myseries (version 1)2.csv",sep="/",header=T,format=%m/%">
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: a paste of at least some of `myseries (version 1)2.csv` would help greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting format into " ", like this

```
format="%m/%d/%Y"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip,but now there is a different message saying:

Comment: tbl<-as.xts(read.zoo("~//Documents//thesis research//myseries (version 1)2.csv",sep="/",header=T,format="%m/%d/%Y"))
Error in read.table(file, ...) : more columns than column names

Comment: Strange,my columns are-date,Y,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6

Comment: This explains how to ask a question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example